# Moving the Expandable List view indicator top or bottom

Tags: android

The indicator can be moved right side of the screen but how to move it top or bottom. I have given the screenshot i want to move the indicator parallel to the texts.

[image]

Comment: I do not see the screen shot.

Comment: what you can't see..indicator is on right side bottom??

Comment: No, i do not see any screenshot or image.

Comment: i have edited it....can you now see it...

Comment: I was also editing. There is a link to the image now.